# What software can I use to create a web-based data-flow diagram with selectable layers?

Tags: diagram

I want to create a simplified data flow diagram that can be accessed via a web browser and allows users to select the layers they want to display.

So for example, if I receive datasets for apples, oranges and bananas that all flow through to a fruit-datamart, the user would see a list of checkboxes (or similar) containing selectable objects for each of these three individual fruits.  If they check "apples" it will show the DFD for apple data.  If they check "oranges", the DFD for orange data would be placed on top of the previously selected apple DFD, thus both DFDs showing at the same time.  I might even have additional layers to show more detail for each fruit data flow.  Any combination of layers can be checked/unchecked by the user to allow them to make the diagram as simple or complex/busy as they like.

Can anybody point me in the direction of software I can use to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is off-topic for this forum. You're looking for an application which uses databases - this has nothing to do with database administration. Take a look at the software-recommendations forum. Take the forum tour and check out the "help us to help you" blog - both at bottom left of the page. I'm going to have to vote to close this.

Comment: Apologies... I looked for what I thought was the most appropriate forum, but clearly not well enough!  Thanks for rectifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/tour/data_flow_diagram lucid chart is what I use for some of our databases. Just so I can keep an understanding of how our databases are set up.
And the free version does support layers.